# Trade period (winter and summer) for Korean football league

Tags: football, trade

When do the winter and summer trade periods start and end for the Korean professional football leagues League 1 and 2?

Are they the same as European leagues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the K League Regulation Chapter 2, Article 5, the player registration period is 12 weeks from the 1st of January.
So that may be March 25 Saturday this year (2023).
The above is the regular registration period.

The additional registration period is for four weeks, but it is not specified in the official regulation book. It may be announced later.